# Having a unqiue counter per User for a different model in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to know what the best way to have a model `Receipt` where the model has an ID field that is unique to each Django User, that won't have issues with asynchronous requests. There is still a separate main ID field added by default, but I would like to have a separate ID for the receipts so that I can display this ID for each User so that their receipt numbers start from 1 when they go to their receipt list.

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    txn_type = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    correction = models.ForeignKey(
        ReceiptCorrection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None, null=True
```

I understand you can check the last number and then just increment by one, but won't that have issues if two computers are running the same user and they both make a receipt at the same time?

I appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: You can use UUID field which can generate unique identifiers: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uuidfield-django-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the "unique counter per User" you mean the code series per User. So I would create a new model `ReceiptCodeSeries`

```py
from django.db import transaction, models


class ReceiptCodeSeries(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    series_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # Optional fields
    prefix = models.CharField(default="2021")
    suffix_length = models.IntegerField(default=4)

    @classmethod
    def get_next_code(cls, user):
        with transaction.atomic():
            series = cls.objects.select_for_update().get(user=user)
            series.series_count += 1
            series.save()
            return series.prefix + str(series.ticket_series_count).zfill(series.suffix_length)
```

This approach locks the code series for each `get_next_code` call so parallel requests will be fine.

**Example usage:**

```py
>>> code_series = ReceiptCodeSeries.objects.get(user=some_user)
>>> print(code_series.series_count)
0
>>> ReceiptCodeSeries.get_next_code(some_user)
"2021-0001"
>>> code_series.refresh_from_db()
>>> print(code_series.series_count)
1
```

If you want to learn more about this approach, please read a great article from [Haki Benita - How to Manage Concurrency in Django Models](https://hakibenita.com/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models)

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Exactly what I was looking for. And the explanation is great.